# Docker containers and local cURL call

Tags: curl, docker, dockerfile

I have trouble to make a cURL call between two docker containers on the same servers.

You will found all containers that are running :

[image: here]

"dashboard" container hosts a webapp reachable with the URL https://www.myapp.com/

"api" container hosts another webapp reachable with the URL https://api.myapp.com

I can't make a cURL call to https://api.myapp.com from within the dashboard container. I got a timeout error everytime.

Maybe there is a routing issue or something else?

The only way that work for now is to make a curl to the URL using the "local notation" http://air360-api:8082/.

I'm using multiple DockerFile with the docker run command.

Can you help me about this ? Thanks !

PS : URLs have been faked, don't try to call them :D

---

**Edited 1** Add the dockerfile / init :

I start my docker instances by running the following cmd :

*docker run -t -d -p "80:80" -p "443:443" --dns "8.8.8.8" --dns "8.8.4.4" --link "dashboard-dev" --link "dashboard" --link "api" --link "media" --link "front "apache"*

Here the dockerfile of the API container. It's the same as the dashboard dockerfile with just differents projects :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install ua-parser --no-cache-dir

# Set environment variables
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:8082"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"

# Copy files to app directory
COPY . /app

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app/API-Project

# Restore NuGet packages
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

# Open up port
EXPOSE 8082

# Run the app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

Comment: Post your docker-compose file

Comment: @TarunLalwani : just edited the question. Do you have an idea in mind ?

Comment: Are you running each container individually using `docker run`? You should be using `docker-compose` your case. Also `--link` is now deprecated and show be avoided as it will removed in upcoming versions

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing timeouts is likely from some firewall rules (iptables). The solution is "don't do that" by going from container to the outside address/port. As long as your ports inside and outside the container match (e.g. mapping port 80 in the container to 80 on the host) then you can make the change completely transparently to your containers.

Place your containers on the same docker network, and use docker networking to talk container-to-container (rather than using a link). Then use an alias for your container on the network to connect container-to-container but using the outside address. Here's an example I have from a traefik container with the network alias, the "proxy" network was created in advance with a `docker network create -d overlay proxy` (this is for swarm mode, so remove the `-d overlay` if you are only running these on a single host).

Here's the relevant parts of my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: proxy

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.4
    networks:
    - proxy:
        aliases:
        - proxy.example.com
    ports:
    - target: 80
      protocol: tcp
      published: 80
      mode: ingress
```

With that, any other container on the proxy network that connects to "proxy.example.com" will go directly to the traefik container. Replace traefik with your own apache container and hostname to apply this to your scenario.